# How to compare two columns of two csv files with awk?

Tags: awk

I have two csv files I need to compare against one column.

My `member.csv` file looks like:

```
ID|lastName|firstName
01|Lastname01|Firstname01
02|Lastname02|Firstname02
```

The second file `check-ID.csv` looks like:

```
Lastname01|Name01|pubID01|Hash01
Lastname02|Name02|pubID02|Hash02a
Lastname03|Name03|pubID03|Hash03
Lastname02|Name02|pubID02|Hash02b
Lastname01|Name01|pubID01|Hash01b
```

--> `Lastname03` is not in my `member.csv` !

What I want is to check if the value of the first column of `check-ID.csv` is equal to value of second column in `member.csv`.

My attempt with `script.awk` is

```
NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1; b[$1]=$0; next} 
$2==a[$1]{ delete b[$1]}

END{for (i in b ) print b[i]}
```

executing with

`awk -f script.awk check-ID.csv member.csv`

The problem is that the result is not filtered.

I like to get a filtered and sorted output so only members are listed like this:

```
Lastname01|Name01|pubID01|Hash01
Lastname01|Name01|pubID01|Hash01b
Lastname02|Name02|pubID02|Hash02a
Lastname02|Name02|pubID02|Hash02b
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following. I think you were close only thing is you could change your Input_files reading sequence. Where I am reading `members` Input_file first and then `check-ID.csv` because later Input_file has all details in it which needs to be printed and we need to only check for 2nd field from members Input_file.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="|"
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$2]
  next
}
($1 in a)
' members.csv check-ID.csv | 
sort -t'|' -k1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                             ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                            ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS="|"                          ##Setting field separator as | here.
}
FNR==NR{                          ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first Input_file named members.csv is being read.
  a[$2]                           ##Creating array a with index 2nd field here.
  next                            ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($1 in a)                         ##Checking condition if 1st field is preent in a then print that line.
' members.csv check-ID.csv |      ##Mentioning Input_file names here and sending its output to sort command.
sort -t'|' -k1                    ##Sorting output(which we got from awk command above) by setting separator as | and by first field.
```