# How to compare four columns in a csv with awk?

Tags: awk

This is a follow-up question of [How to compare two columns of two csv files with awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63702274/how-to-compare-two-columns-of-two-csv-files-with-awk/63702400#63702400).

I have two csv files I need to compare against one column.

My `member.csv` file looks like:

```
ID|lastName|firstName|pubID
01|Lastname01|Firstname01|pubID01
02|Lastname02|Firstname02|pubID02
03|Lastname03|Firstname03|pubID03
```

The second file `check-ID.csv` looks like:

```
Lastname01|Name01|pubID01|Hash01
Lastname02|Name02|pubID02|Hash02a
LastnAme0X|Name03|pubID03|Hash03
Lastname04|Name04|pubID04|Hash04
Lastname02b|Name02|pubID02|Hash02b
Lastname01|Name01|pubID01|Hash01b
```

--> `Lastname04` is not in my `member.csv` !

What I want is to check if the value of the first column of `check-ID.csv` is equal to value of second column in `member.csv` OR if the value of the fourth column of `check-ID.csv` is equal to value of third column in `member.csv`

My attempt is

```
awk 'BEGIN{  FS="|"} FNR==NR{  a[$2]; b[$4]; next }($1 in a  || $3 in b) ' member.csv check-ID.csv  | sort -t'|' -k1
```

But clearly I dont get the conditions right.

I like to get a filtered and sorted output so only members are listed like this:

```
Lastname01|Name01|pubID01|Hash01
Lastname01|Name01|pubID01|Hash01b
Lastname02|Name02|pubID02|Hash02a
Lastname02b|Name02|pubID02|Hash02b
LastnAme0X|Name03|pubID03|Hash03
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="|"
}
{  gsub(/\r/,"")  }
FNR==NR{
  a[$2]
  b[$4]
  next
}
($1 in a) || ($3 in b)
' members.csv  check-ID.csv |
sort -t'|' -k1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                              ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                             ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS="|"                           ##Setting field separator as | here.
}
{  gsub(/\r/,"")  }                ##Globally substituting all control M characters in all lines.
FNR==NR{                           ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which will be TRUE when members.csv is being read.
  a[$2]                            ##Creating array a with index of 2nd field.
  b[$4]                            ##Creating array b with index of 4th field here.
  next                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($1 in a) || ($3 in b)             ##For check-ID.csv Input_file checking condition if either 1st field is present in a OR 3rd field is present in b then print that line.
' members.csv  check-ID.csv |      ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
sort -t'|' -k1                     ##Sending output of awk code to sort command and sorting it by first field with setting field separator as | for all lines.
```

Comment: @LukasCB, it worked fine for me. Could you please check your Input_files have control M characters by doing `cat -v Input_file` on both the files and let me know then?

Comment: besides some "Umlauts" the file seems fine and I cannot see control M characters. The pubID in my actual member-file is in column 6 but I changed `b[$4]` to `b[$6]` for testing.

Comment: @LukasCB, IMHO answers are always given as per shown samples only. Your samples are showing its 2nd and 4th fields in members file and 1st and 3rd for other. In case field numbers are NOT same in your actual file then change them accordingly and this should fly then.